# mongodb update is always inseting document with {upsert:true}

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I have a problem with update function on node.js

```
details.update({ id: page.id },res,{upsert : true});
```

this function always insert document even if documents with **{ id: page.id }** exists.

Can you help me please

Comment: are sure that database id is type of page.id ?

Comment: yes i even tested that directly on mongodb

Comment: can you show us some records from database? especially those duplicated.